# How to forward audio/video data from a user's browser(client) to a server?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

## **What I am Doing**

I have a javascript file that uses `getUserMedia()` to get the audio and video from the client’s computer. How do I implement computer vision to video feed which was extracted from the camera using javascript `getUserMedia()` and speech recognition to audio feed which was extracted from the microphone using javascript `getUserMedia()` using python?

**Why do I want to use Python?**

I want to use python because I have already written all the code to run this locally on my machine, using flask but to run on other computers I have to use javascript to access the client's mic and cam and can't use python to do that or python would detect a mic and cam in the server instead of the client's machine.

## **What I  Tried**

**Attempt #1**

I have tried using [js2py](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py) to translate `.js` file to `.py` file using:

```
js2py.translate_file(static/sketch.js', 'sketch.py')
from sketch import sketch
# I use getUserMedia() function after that from the .py file
```

I got an error which I found out was a too large `.js` file error.

**Attempt #2**

I looked at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) docs articles:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Fetching_data

I got really confused about how to use Ajax so didn’t even try because I didn’t know what to do. I am highly leaning towards thinking this could solve my problem but I could be wrong that’s is why I am asking this question.

## **Underlying Question**

My question is how to deliver audio/video data from a user's browser to a server?

Comment: [example code](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/flask/web%20camera%20in%20browser%20-%20canvas%20-%20take%20image%20and%20upload%20to%20server) for sending webcam from browser to flask, modify in flask (using cv2) and send back from flask to browser. All this need code in JavaScript which hast to run in browser - so converting to Python is useless.

Comment: all code is in one file [app-3-take-image-and-upload-and-sendback-3-fetch.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/flask/web%20camera%20in%20browser%20-%20canvas%20-%20take%20image%20and%20upload%20to%20server/app-3-take-image-and-upload-and-sendback-3-fetch.py) so you can simply copy and run it. It uses JavaScript (modern `fetch()` instead of old `XMLHttpRequest()`) to send data to url in flask and get result - so it is `AJAX`.

Comment: @furas sorry for the late reply, it worked! Could you please post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @furas is there also a way to do this with audio?